# Azure Frontdoor multi path routing not working with storage static web apps

Tags: azure, networking, next.js, azure-static-web-app, azure-front-door

I've been trying to setup Front Door (standard) endpoint to route two azure storage static websites. But thats is not working as expected.I need both static apps under same domain name but different path of URL like this.

```
www.something.com  ->   static app 1
www.something.com/client  ->  static app 2
```

The pattern to match I have added for the static app 1 is --> /* and the origin path is --> /.
Same way I have added the pattern to match for the static app 2 is --> /client/* and the origin path is --> /

The first app is working as expected. But the second app route is not working as expected and I am getting 400 error.

Both of the static apps created using nextjs and exported as a staticapp. For each apps I have created separate origin groups and pointed to route rules. I am not sure what configuration I am missing here. Can someone help me on this?

Comment: can you please share the routing rules?

Comment: For the app 1 route path is /* and the second app the route path is /client/*.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the default document name for your second static website is correct?

Comment: yes I have set that to index.html and the error page also to index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue by adding basepath in our nextjs application. So then that will load the scripts from that path.

```
const nextConfig = {
  basePath:'/client'
};
```

Then the scrips specified in the index.html will load as below

```
<link
      rel="preload"
      href="/client/_next/static/css/5650791e71b69c72.css"
      as="style"
    />
```

I hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

I have created setup Front Door (standard) endpoint to route two azure storage static websites like below:

[image]

To resolve this issue add a routing rule like below:

[image]

***Front Door was set up properly for the first static app, but the second app might require some additional configuration.***

- Ensure that the second static app is correctly deployed and has a unique URL for access. You can verify this by clicking directly on the URL for the second app and check the origin path  for the second app is set to `/client`
- Make sure the second app's routing rule is properly configured. Confirm that `/client/*` is the pattern to match, and choose the origin group for the second app.
- Check if there are any conflicting routing rules that might be causing the 400 error. Other restrictions that have contradictory patterns or origin groups may be preventing traffic from reaching the second app.

When I try these changes it redirects successfully like below:

[image]

The URL that Azure Front Door will use to build the request forwarded to the origin is rewritten using this path. This path isn't offered by default. As a result, when making a request to the origin, Azure Front Door will use the incoming URL path. Moreover, you have the option of specifying a wildcard path, which will replicate all portions of the incoming route that match the request path's origin. Case distinction applies to the origin path.

***Reference***:

[Configure Azure Front Door Route | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/standard-premium/how-to-configure-route#create-a-new-azure-front-door-standardpremium-route)

[Routing rule matching - Azure Front Door | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-route-matching?pivots=front-door-standard-premium)

Comment: I tried this configuration. The first html page loads fine. But the css or js not loading and giving 404 error. I have created a nextjs app and the path specified in the html as `<link rel="preload" href="/_next/static/css/5650791e71b69c72.css" as="style"/>`

Comment: its look like you are using Next.js to build your application and the CSS file is generated as part of the Next.js build process.Ensure that the path to the CSS file is correct and matches the file structure generated by Next.js. If the CSS file is not located at /public/_next/static/css/5650791e71b69c72.css, you will need to update the path accordingly.try accessing the CSS file directly in your browser If the file is not found, it could indicate that the path is incorrect  You can also try running npm run build to rebuild the application and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: Yes I am exporting the nextjs app as a static app and hosting in azure storage static. We can directly access this site using the static app url. But accessing through the frontdoor is the problem. Applying the rule will load only the first index.html. css and js referenced in the html is not loading properly.

Comment: Then you need to check routing rules in Front Door are correctly configured to route requests for the CSS and JS files to the appropriate origin group. Ensure that the pattern to match and the origin path are correctly specified for each origin group. Check the file paths in the HTML source try, file paths should be relative to the root of ur static app. try to check Front Door logs to see any errors related to file serving or routing.

Comment: I have added the routing rules as per the documentation. Also the paths are relative to the HTML source. If I add the file full path in the rule only thats loading.